# Arranging Exam Questions

Tags: combinatorics

Given 4 questions in algebra, 3 questions in geometry and 3 questions in trigonometry, in how many ways can we arrange these questions so the algebra questions are next to each other and the geometry questions are next to each other too? 
I tried referring to the algebra questions as one body and the geometry questions as a one body too.
So now i have questions to arrange in a line which has 5! chances **but** I was stuck when it comes to the internal order of the algebra and geometry questions. 
the algebra's internal order is 4! and the geometry internal order is 3!, but i didn't know how i can multiply these orders with the former result (5!). For example if we have 3 people and 2 want to set next to each other we refer to them is 1 body, then get 2! chances of sitting them in a line and they can change so we multiply by 2, hence the result is 2*2!. 
I'm stuck in doing the same in the given questions. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: What you suggested is correct: multiply $5!$ (ways to order the 5 groups of questions) with $4!$ (ways to order the algebra questions) and $3!$ (ways to order the geometry questions).

Comment: You write _and they can change so we multiply by 2_ when it should be instead "...and they can change so we multiply by $2!$", and it just so happens that $2!=2$.  Understanding this will help you understand your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

When we use the Box and Packet Method in order to Solve a Permutation and Combination Problem we need to be careful while making Packets.

1. Create a Packet of 4 Algebra Questions, a Packet of 3 Geometry Questions.
2. Now we 1 packet of ALGEBRA. 1 Packet of GEOMETRY, and 3 Questions of Trigonometry.

We now have::: 5!(packets in total) * (4!)(Internal Permutation) * (4!)(Internal Permutation).

Result = 69,120.

Comment: Be careful.  There are $4$ algebra questions but only $3$ geometry questions.